# How to find an unknown Steam User

Tags: steam

I was playing with someone on Ark: Survival recently, I CTD'd and couldn't get his information. Are there any means that I could find this user's Steam account even though he hasn't logged in since?

I know of the function `View: Players` in Steam, but it only shows me the last 24 hours and I haven't played with this player in 3-4 days. Is there a way I could extend the view recent players function on Steam? Is there a record of this somewhere? Or do I have any further options?

Comment: Can I just ask what you mean by CTD

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox CTD = Crash to Desktop

Comment: Also in case anyone is not familiar with View -> Players, you can see all the players you have played with recently, any steam connected game, even if they are not in your friends list.

Comment: On Steam Client go to:<Steam name> > Friends > Recently Played With. As of right now I am able to go back as far as the 19th.

Comment: Cheers mate! That works perfectly didnt see that Thanks

Comment: Mano, your comment should be made into an answer, if it answers the question..

Comment: @Mano I left a CW answer since your suggestion solved OP's problem. If at any time you decide to make your own answer, ping me here (or on my answer as this comment may get removed) and I'll remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@Mano has pointed out in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/158613/mano), you can achieve this in the Steam client (or via the website) by going to your Steam profile, clicking *Friends*, then selecting *Recently Played With*

Here's a link you can follow to view it on the web: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/YOURSTEAMID/friends/coplay/