# Find steam account associated with username in Paladins(Hirez)

Tags: steam, paladins

So I met someone ingame, Paladins, and he was referring to me by my steam username, and as we were exchanging not so pleasant pleasantries I couldn't ask him.

So, I guess it is possible to find steam account of a paladins player. How do I do that?

Or it it is something else then I want to know how can he/she know it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find an unknown Steam User](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301377/how-to-find-an-unknown-steam-user)